# Gremlin/Neptune vertex lookup by property using gremlinpython

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Using the graph traversal object `g`, I can look up a vertex by ID:

```
>>> g.V().has("~id", "foo").toList()
[vp[category->my category], vp[title->my title], vp[description->my description], vp[myprop->my property]]
```

Looking up by "category" also works:

```
>>> g.V().has("category", "my category").toList()
[vp[category->my category], vp[title->my title], vp[description->my description], vp[myprop->my property]]
```

But looking up via another property produces no results:

```
>>> g.V().has("myprop", "my property").toList()
[]
```

What might be different? The values are simple uppercase letters with dashes, so I doubt there's any escaping/unescaping going on.

(property names have been changed to protect the innocent)

Comment: that should just work afaik. perhaps try other versions of `has()` - maybe try the overload with the vertex label as the starting argument, thus `g.V().has('my-vertex-label', 'myprop','my property')`. might not be able to solve this one without the real failing example.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load process was overwriting the expected property value with a different one, but not providing sufficient feedback to identify that behavior.